# XSLT Sorting a table with info from external documents

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have major problems with this task and i can't figure out how to do the sorting.

I'm trying to sort a table in XSLT where I'm importing an .XSL. In this .XSL i have two external .XSL referenced. Output should be html.

mainXSL.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" media-type="image/svg" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

                <xsl:variable name="fileA" select="document(/importFiles/docs/@fileA)" />
                <xsl:variable name="fileB" select="document(/importFiles/docs/@fileB)" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title> 
                    Task1
                </title>
            </head>        
                <body>
                    <table align="center" border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th>column_1</th>
                            <th>column_2</th>
                        </tr>

                        <xsl:for-each select="$fileA/numbers/number">
                            <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="current_node" select="position()"/>
                                    <tr>                                  
                                        <td class="_fileA"><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
                                        <td class="_fileB"><xsl:value-of select="$fileB//animal[$current_node]" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                    </body>
               </html> 
</xsl:template>
```

index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mainXSL.xsl"?>

<importFiles>
    <docs fileA = "fileA.xml" />
    <docs fileB = "fileB.xml" /> 
</importFiles>
```

fileA.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <numbers>
            <number>A</number>
            <number>C</number>
            <number>B</number>
            <number>E</number>
            <number>D</number>
        </numbers>
```

fileB.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <animals>
            <animal>dog</animal>
            <animal>horse</animal>
            <animal>cow</animal>
            <animal>snake</animal>
            <animal>spider</animal>
        </animals>
```

So the numbers in fileA.xml are attatched to an animal on the same row in fileB.xml

What i get now is a table:

1 - dog

2 - horse

3 - cow

4 - snake

5 - spider

What i want to get is:

1 - dog

2 - cow

3 - horse

4 - spider

5 - snake

I can't figure out how to sort the columns together , only column_1, after the for-each loop.
Tried to find similar problems here but to no avail. 
Ps. sorry for the formatting, not sure the indentations are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't want the `<xsl:sort select="." order="ascending"/>` and remove it and then you can use `<td class="_fileA"><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></td>` for the first column and for the second column use `<td class="_fileB"><xsl:value-of select="$fileB//animal[position() = current()]" /></td>`.

As the complete stylesheet I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" media-type="text/html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:variable name="fileA" select="document(/importFiles/docs/@fileA)" />
    <xsl:variable name="fileB" select="document(/importFiles/docs/@fileB)" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title> 
                    Task1
                </title>
            </head>        
            <body>
                <table align="center" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>column_1</th>
                        <th>column_2</th>
                    </tr>

                    <xsl:for-each select="$fileA/numbers/number">

                        <tr>                                  
                            <td class="_fileA"><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></td>
                            <td class="_fileB"><xsl:value-of select="$fileB//animal[position() = current()]" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and that gives me the output

```
column_1    column_2
1   dog
2   cow
3   horse
4   spider
5   snake
```

Online at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/test201710120301.xml.

Comment: using position() will give me numbers in ascending order in the first column. Second column remains unchanged.

Comment: @goat_pee, sorry, yes, the second column needs to be changed as well, see edit, I got confused by the name of the variable `current_node` you had.

Comment: Thnx for the input. For some reason this won't sort the first column and the second column is empty...I can't imagine doing this without the sort() but then again, i'm just a rookie when it comes to XSLT.

Comment: I have added a full example XSLT of what I suggested, seems to do the job just fine for me looking at the result.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! However, i might have missed a vital detail in my question. Let's say that fileA.xml contains letters instead of numbers. Could i use position() as an index instead?